# Assign Orders To Existing Customer ( in WooCommerce )

Tags: woocommerce

i need to assign some orders to another customer user.

is there a way to do it bulk in phpmyadmin?

order number range : 23000 : 24000.

target customer user id = 89

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **— updated 2 —** *(corrected some typo errors in the code)*

Here is a **PHP custom function that will do the job**, using a for loop to iterate in your order number range. It will use also [**`get_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) and [**`update_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) functions to check for **`'_customer_user'`** met_key in the orders and to update that customer ID value.

> You will do a database backup before, running this function.

So here is the code of this function:

```
function cristmas_bulk_editing_orders( ){

    if(!is_admin()) return; // Will work only from Admin Backed.
    else {

        $new_costumer_id = 89;

        // Iterating with a for loop through a range of numbers
        for( $order_id = 23000; $order_id <= 24000; $order_id++ ){

            // Getting the postmeta customer ID for 'order' post-type
            $costumer_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true );

            // If it's an existing order and doesn't have already this user ID
            // It update the customer ID
            if( !empty($costumer_id) && $new_costumer_id != $costumer_id )
                update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', $new_costumer_id );
        }
    }

}

cristmas_bulk_editing_orders();
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).

> **You have to use this function only once and to remove it afterwards** *(see below).*

---

**USAGE:**

> Once this code is pasted and saved on **function.php** file, display or reload any Admin page from backend within your browser.

Now you can comment the function this way and save:

```
// cristmas_bulk_editing_orders();
```

Check that the orders have been changed as you want, **and remove all this code**.

**Code is tested and works.**

Comment: thank you for your code. but when i add this code to function.php i got a white page on admin page.

Comment: thank youuuuuu... problem solved.    your code work perfectly.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for the awesome solution . works great...  But I am facing a issue that this is not working for the orders from the guest customers.. Can you please please please help !  I have also put a bounty that I could afford - ----- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507873/assign-orders-from-guest-customers-to-particular-user

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I just liked it but it is not working for just one scenerio ... for the guest customer orders .. Can you please help

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I tested this on totally new version of wordpress , woocommerce , new database, storefront theme.. But the results are same .. So I think data for sample order doesn't matter

Comment: @terminator I have make an answer in [Assign orders from guest customers to particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46675610/3730754) … Try it and let me know