# Assign orders from guest customers to particular user

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311308/assign-orders-to-existing-customer-in-woocommerce) to solve this but this is not working for orders from guest customers .  However this is working fine for the orders belonging to some registered user/customer **but not for the orders belonging to guest customers.**

Solution credit to [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) for  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311308/assign-orders-to-existing-customer-in-woocommerce)

```
function cristmas_bulk_editing_orders(){

    if(!is_admin()) return; // Will work only from Admin Backed.
    else {

        $order_id = 9458;
        $new_customer_id = 479;

            // Getting the postmeta customer ID for 'order' post-type
            $customer_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true );
            var_dump($customer_id);
            // If it's an existing order and doesn't have already this user ID
            // It update the customer ID
            if( !empty($customer_id) && $new_customer_id != $customer_id )
                update_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', $new_customer_id,0);
                echo 'order updated';

    }

}
cristmas_bulk_editing_orders();
```

**ORIGINAL ISSUE**

We imported the orders via woocommerce order export & import plugin from woocommerce team ..

But in the process something went wrong.. Most of the orders were not assigned any customer ..

So now when ever a new customer registers he/she is assigned 1 of these orders automatically ..

So basicallly  all of them see 1 order in their recent orders which belongs to some other guest cusotmer , then they have all the information about other customer . their email etc..

So one option is I find out all the orders(with issues that is no customer assisned to them ) and I assign them to admin ..but this also have some issuses.....

SO is there any other option that these new registered users don't get old orders assigned..

Please help

Comment: Does these guest orders have specific meta value that is different from user orders... and can you give the result for this using guest order id, 2 results for 2 different guest orders would be good:

            `$customer_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true );
            var_dump($customer_id);`

Comment: @ Ali_k   thanks for helping me out  $customer_id is 0 means the guest order which I am pretty sure .. But still I will recheck and get back to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you could try this other similar function based on SQL queries, that should do the trick. Before starting, **make a database backup**. I have add controls (or limitations) like :

- A max date (in `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00` date time format)
- Order number range

So here is that code:

```
function easter_bulk_editing_orders(){

    if( ! is_admin() ) return; // Will work only from Admin Backed.
    else {
        $processed_orders = array();

        // Define the replacement user ID
        $replacement_user_id = '2500';

        // Define the DATE LIMIT for guest orders max date limit
        $max_date = '2017-12-09 00:00:00';

        // Define an order range
        $order_id_min = '0';
        $order_id_max = '100000';

        global $wpdb;

        // Get all guest orders below a defined max date
        $old_guest_orders = $wpdb->get_results( "
            SELECT pm.*, p.post_date
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
            WHERE pm.post_id BETWEEN $order_id_min AND $order_id_max
            AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
            AND ( pm.meta_value LIKE '0' OR pm.meta_value LIKE '' )
            AND p.post_date <= '$max_date'
        " );

        foreach( $old_guest_orders as $guest_order ){
            $meta_id = $guest_order->meta_id;

            $wpdb->query( "
                UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
                SET pm.meta_value = '$replacement_user_id'
                WHERE pm.meta_id = '$meta_id'
            " );
            // Set each order ID in an array
            $processed_orders[] = $guest_order->post_id;
        } 
        // Testing ( raw output of processed orders IDS )
        var_dump($processed_orders);
    }
}

// Run the function
easter_bulk_editing_orders();
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

You have to use this function only once and to remove it afterwards (see below).

---

USAGE:

> Once this code is pasted and saved on function.php file, display or reload any Admin page from backend within your browser.
>   Now you can comment the function this way and save:

```
// easter_bulk_editing_orders();
```

Check that the orders have been changed as you want, and remove all this code.

Code is tested and works.

Comment: works awesome.. thanks a lot .. you saved my life ..   thanks a lot once again

Comment: Just a note on the sql string from something I may be wrong about if I've remembered incorrectly. I also am tidy with code, starting a string on a new line indented, but I remember having to add a trim() to the method in the DB class before it made the DB query to get rid of the white space as it wasn't caching because the string didn't start with SELECT. I'm not sure if Wordpress also does this.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your importing so try to re-import. Have you tried WP All Import Premium. It will import anything with drag and drop titles, categories, and meta fields. you can also assign new meta name to post meta while importing. If you need more help then share more details.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I imported this 6 months back  and I don't have the old backup of orders.  So there is no way of reimporting.. rather I want to run a query and update the customers of all the guest orders .. either by assigning to real customer or assign them to the admin

Comment: is the meta values available or not? if available then i can help otherwise no one can help.

Comment: meta values.. ?   Actually the code I posted works fine for case 1)  if a order with id  9458 is from user (id= 479)  and i wish to assign this to other user - 500..  THis works fine..  But for case 2 where order belongs to guest that is customer id is 0 then this doeen't work ... means this part is not working update_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', $new_customer_id,0);